# Who said that Allingham "polished her prose until it shone over-bright," and where?

Tags: margery-allingham, quote-source

Somebody read to me from a book about Allingham long ago that she would "polish her prose until it shone over-bright" and then dictate it to her husband to reduce it to a more readable vernacular. I think it was a line from a biography describing an interview with surviving relatives. I've repeated this line many times, and then recently went to track down its source again--and I can't.

What I *did* find was this line by Allingham herself:

> I write every paragraph four times - once to get my meaning down, once to put in anything I have left out, once to take out anything that seems unnecessary, and once to make the whole thing sound as if I had only just thought of it.

Which has the gist of the quote I remember, but doesn't mention dictating to her husband, is in her own voice rather than a third party, and doesn't use the phrase "shone over-bright," which I remember quite clearly.

So, where did that description of her writing process come from?

Comment: I had have no luck with finding this.  Are you sure it was allingham?

Comment: I've found multiple references to her dictating though, but none referencing polishing.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of [this quote about Willa Cather](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NgJrPwlZKigC&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=%22polish+her+prose+until+it%22&source=bl&ots=ijwCg9dnQl&sig=ACfU3U0c8JKEvHsNMgX2TsLfsuS6h-_3bg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH1b2PjNbnAhXwyKYKHRl8D4EQ6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22polish%20her%20prose%20until%20it%22&f=false) - *"She would polish her prose until it shone like a jewel"*